# Add absolute path to img in jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to pull some data from a particular div on an external site, pre-append a URL to img src links, which are relative, to make the absolute, then put that html in a div.  Ignoring cross site issues...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var $thePage = jQuery('<div>');
  jQuery($thePage).load("https://example.com div.myitem");
  jQuery($thePage).find('img').attr('src', function (i, src) {
    var newsrc = "https://example.com" + src;
    return newsrc;
  });
  jQuery("#testdiv").html($thePage);
});
```

The html is displayed in the div, but the img links aren't updated.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the current result and the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery.load is asynchronous, so you should do stuff with returned data within a callback.

```
  jQuery($thePage).load("https://example.com div.myitem", function () {
    // replace stuff here
    // show output on page here
  });
```